# Datetime render issue on Magento admin grid

Tags: magento-1, grid, order-grid, datetime

In our Magento EE dashboard sometimes DateTime column of grids (orders, customer orders) showing incorrect values, this only sometimes, not all times. Maybe it depends on the session, maybe it has the caching problem on Magento. 
[image]

[image]
I could not catch the issue, not any messages related to this issue on error logs. Has somebody faced such type of issue?

Comment: How do the entries in the database look like?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl issue is temporary, after sometimes datetime values rendered correctly on this screenshot. Entries in database is valid like "2015-09-10 02:20:22"

Comment: Interesting. So the entries in the database are always correct, just the rendering differes *sometimes*? Can you reproduce it somehow (eg with different browsers)?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I could not reproduce it, client reports me this issue

Comment: Do you have a module that alters/overwrite grids or grid columns (like Advanced Magento Grid)?

Comment: @aki No module overwrites, it is class of core Magento grid

Comment: I think this can be caused by translation. I'm saying this because that column uses a renderer and calls formated translated dates.

Or maybe you can look at this issue from another point of view. Usually Magento doesn't behave that way. Maybe the client has some browser modules that identifies dates and does something with them. Think about skype module that identifies phone numbers and puts a button to call.

Comment: I think it has something with the month february as i can see in screenshot :). So, check translations and play with them

Comment: In particular translations of Magento backend there are bugs with date displaying and saving, f.g. working in Cestina will block you from saving forms with changed date - the format is wrong. Is is default translation, what language?

Comment: @versedi locale is English(US), timezone is PST

Comment: Please let me know below things:

1. Magento timezone
2. DB timezone
3. UTC time for the instant when you see this error (what to check if its related to time gap)
4. Using any CDN for serving js files if yes what is timezone for your CDN account?
5. Is this column is default one or you customized this.
6. Performed any other change in frontend or backend for date format related thing
7. Any error in logs related to fetching timezone from DB.

Comment: @SourabhModi Magento timezone is PST, DB timezone is UTC, I could not reproduce the issue, no CDN, not customized column, no changes related to date format, no error logs.